# error occured instantiating job to be executed in Quartz sheduler

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

```
package org.quartz;      
import org.quartz.Scheduler;     
import org.quartz.JobDetail;    
import org.quartz.JobKey;    
import org.quartz.Trigger;    
import org.quartz.Job;    
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;    
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;    
import org.quartz.SchedulerException;     
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;     
import static org.quartz.JobBuilder.*;     
import static org.quartz.TriggerBuilder.*;     
import static org.quartz.SimpleScheduleBuilder.*;    
import static org.quartz.CronScheduleBuilder.*;    
import static org.quartz.CalendarIntervalScheduleBuilder.*;    
import static org.quartz.DateBuilder.*;    

class myJob implements Job {           
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)    
      throws JobExecutionException
    {
      System.out.println("Hello!  HelloJob is executing.");
    }
}

public class schedule{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{    
         System.out.println("Java working");

         try {
                    // Grab the Scheduler instance from the Factory                 
                JobKey jobKeyA = new JobKey("myJob", "group1");    
                JobDetail jobA = JobBuilder.newJob(myJob.class)    
                .withIdentity(jobKeyA).build();

                        // Trigger the job to run now, and then every 40 seconds
                Trigger trigger1 = TriggerBuilder    
                        .newTrigger()    
                        .withIdentity("dummyTriggerName1", "group1")    
                        .withSchedule(
                            CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0/5 * * * * ?"))
                        .build();

                      Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();

                        // and start it off    
                      scheduler.start();

                        // Tell quartz to schedule the job using our trigger

                      scheduler.scheduleJob(jobA, trigger1);


            } catch (SchedulerException se) {                   
                se.printStackTrace();
            }    
    }       
}
```

And I am getting an error of instantiating job and then obviously All triggers of Job  set to ERROR state.
What is the reason? 
and please help it is very important.
provide me the answer. 
**Error**

```
[ERROR] 28 Dec 03:03:30.008 PM
DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread
[org.quartz.core.ErrorLogger]
```

An error occured instantiating job to be executed. job= 'group1.myJob'

```
org.quartz.SchedulerException: Problem instantiating class
'org.quartz.myJob'  [See nested exception:
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class
org.quartz.simpl.SimpleJobFactory can not access a member of class
org.quartz.myJob with modifiers ""]
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleJobFactory.newJob(SimpleJobFactory.java:58)
    at org.quartz.simpl.PropertySettingJobFactory.newJob(PropertySettingJobFactory.java:69)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.initialize(JobRunShell.java:127)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:375)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class
org.quartz.simpl.SimpleJobFactory can not access a member of class
org.quartz.myJob with modifiers ""
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:102)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:436)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleJobFactory.newJob(SimpleJobFactory.java:56)
    ... 3 more [INFO] 28 Dec 03:03:30.013 PM
DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread
[org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore]
```

All triggers of Job group1.myJob set to ERROR state.

Comment: Can you add stack trace of the exception that you are getting?

Comment: yups....i have given the error exception

Comment: Please Provide me the solution

Comment: Make your job class public i.e public class myJob and take it out to separate file i think it will solve the issue.Please let me know if it works

Comment: Thanks ..so much . It is running Perfectly

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your job class has to be `public`. Otherwise, the JobBuilder can not read it.

```
public class myJob implements Job {           
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
      System.out.println("Hello!  HelloJob is executing.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Great point :) Such silly things create so much of problems :) Thanks

Answer (score 3):

1. Class should be public class
2. Default constructor should be public

Answer (score 0):

Improvement on top of the solution above. The class can be marked with static keyword to improve the efficiency. The job will be created each time when the scheduled slot occured.

```
public static class MyJob implements Job {

        @Override
        public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
            System.out.println("My job is called");
        }
    }
```